# Is it possible?: Behavior t [Behavior t a] -> Behavior t [a]

Tags: haskell, frp, reactive-banana

Is there a way to have a `Behavior t [a]` where the values of [a] at time t are the values contained in a `Behavior t [Behavior t a]` at time t? I.e, a function with the type of:

```
Behavior t [Behavior t a] -> Behavior t [a]
```

If this is not possible, is that because of a logical impossibility or a limitation in reactive-banana?

Comment: Type signature is valid, can you explain what exactly is your problem?
If I get it right, you want to do some sort of filtering?

Comment: I don't know reactive-banana, but there's still definitely a question of whether that type is inhabited.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning "type is inhabited", it lead me to the Curry-Howard isomorphism theorem wiki page on Haskell Wiki.

Comment: Semantically `Behavior a` is `Time -> a` such that `Behavior [Behavior a]` is `Time -> [Time -> a]` while `Behavior [a]` is `Time -> [a]`. Are you looking for something like `fix :: Behavior [Behavior a] -> Behavior [a]; fix as t = map ($ t) (as t)`?

Comment: @Adrian *Highly* suggest playing around with [Software Foundations](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/) or [Certified Programming with Dependent Types](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/) if that stuff interests you.

Comment: I don't think there is one. If there were (and it obeyed fairly simple laws), `Behavior t` would be a Monad. A Monad's join would have type `Behavior t (Behavior t a) -> Behavior t a`, which is almost the same thing. The closest thing I can find in the reactive-banana docs is `switchB`, which I imagine switches to the behavior from the most recent event. `Moment t` is a Monad, but I don't know what it means, and there doesn't seem to be any way to get from a `Moment t` something back to a `Behavior t`. Perhaps if you are making your own framework it could be built from `changes` and `switchB`.

Comment: It's not a logical impossibility, for example, I use a monadic interface to provide a similar feature in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502268/updating-record-when-referenced-by-multiple-data-structures/19506973#19506973. Much of the complexity was in allowing exactly that sort of thing to happen.

Comment: You also might be interested in this paper, http://homepages.cwi.nl/~ploeg/papers/monfrp.pdf, which discusses some of the advantages and disadvantages of Arrows and Monads, both of which are applicative, as abstractions for functional reactive programming. As far as I can tell, reactive-banana fits in a third category of being Applicative, but not being a Monad or an Arrow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The type is trivially inhabited for any `Applicative`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Data.Functor.Identity
import qualified Data.Traversable as T

f' :: (Applicative f) => f [f a] -> f [a]
f' = const $ pure []
```

which is clearly not what you intended. So let's ask for inhabitation of

```
(Traversable t) => Behavior u (t (Behavior u a)) -> Behavior u (t a)
```

or more generally for which applicatives we can construct

```
(T.Traversable t) => f (t (f a)) -> f (t a)
```

This is inhabited for any `f` that is also a monad:

```
f :: (Monad m, T.Traversable t) => m (t (m a)) -> m (t a)
f = join . liftM T.sequence
```

An obvious question arises: If an applicative has such an `f`, does it have to be a monad? The answer is *yes*. We just apply `f` to the `Identity` traversable (one-element collection - the `Traversable` instance of `Identity`) and construct `join` as

```
g :: (Applicative m) => (forall t . (T.Traversable t) => m (t (m a)) -> m (t a))
                     -> (m (m a) -> m a)
g f = fmap runIdentity . f . fmap Identity
```

So our function is inhabited precisely for those applicatives that are also monads.

To conclude: **The function you're seeking would exist if and only if `Behavior` were a `Monad`.** And because it is not, most likely there is no such function. (I believe that if there were a way how to make it a monad, it'd be included in the library.)

Comment: I was nearly compelled by this idea as well, but then I saw that by the model demonstrated in my comment it should be a possible, non-trivial function for any Functor. That obviously still implies Monad, so I guess I'm curious why the model is a monad yet the implementation isn't.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson I guess the reason is that the model `Time -> a` allows us to access any the value at an arbitrary time. But in a FRP implementation this isn't possible, we can generally access "now", or something. I'm not sure, but this could be the reason.

Comment: @PetrPudlák: in the `Reader` type it's possible to define the monadic `join` using the `Applicative` instance: `join ra = runReader <$> ra <*> ask`. I think we can see the issue in this light: `Behavior` lacks a counterpart to `runReader`.

Comment: @LuisCasillas That's a very interesting point! I don't think at all that there should be `runBehavior :: Behavior a -> t -> a`, but ought there not be a `behaviorNow :: Behavior (Behavior a) -> Behavior a` implemented theoretically as `behaviorNow f t = f t t`?

Comment: @J.Abrahamson: I don't know reactive-banana, but Conal's ["Push-pull functional programming"](http://conal.net/papers/push-pull-frp/) does have `time :: Behavior Time` whose model is the `Time -> Time` identity.

Comment: To generalize my earlier point a bit: another way of looking at this is with [representable functors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/representable-functors-3.0.0.3/docs/Data-Functor-Representable.html): any `Functor` isomorphic to `(->) r` (for some `r`) is a `Monad`. In the case of FRP, there is an isomorphism between `Behavior` and `(->) Time` in the **metalanguage** that we use to state the model, but in the object language we cannot implement such a thing.

Comment: Without using dynamic switching (a bit of a pain), the only option seems to be use a `Behavior t [a]` in the first place and update each item in the boring, non-frp way.

Answer (score 2):

As Petr has already indicated, such a function

```
flatten :: Behavior t [Behavior t a] -> Behavior t [a]
```

exists if and only if the type `Behavior t` were a monad.

Here a direct way to see this:

```
join :: Behavior t (Behavior t a) -> Behavior t a
join = map head . flatten . map (:[])

flatten = join . map sequence
```

However, for various reasons, `Behavior t` is *not* a monad in reactive-banana. This is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20890439/403805).